# Icicles: Why candidates are on the right side?

Tags: window-splitting

windows 10 , Emacs 26.1, Icicles

In my **init.el**

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/icicles")
(require 'icicles)
(icy-mode 1)
```

And when I type the candidates are show on the right side.

[image]

Why?

Is it possible to candidates to show ABOVE mini-buffer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prefer vertical splits over horizontal ones](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/39034/prefer-vertical-splits-over-horizontal-ones)

Comment: This has nothing to do with Icicles in particular. See option `split-width-threshold` - set it to a large number.

Comment: I must set not big number. I need to set "split-width-threshold" to nil. If this
   is nil, ‘split-window-sensibly’ is not allowed to split a window
   horizontally. This is exact what I need. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the candidates on the left side, with the original buffer on the right?

Comment: @npostavs No, I want candidates to show in separate buffer exact above mini-buffer

Comment: So you want icicle to do horizontal split, but not other commands?

Comment: @npostavs I solved the problem by set "split-width-threshold" to nil

Comment: Oh, I missed that. Your comment saying that above is a bit terse, I suggest turning it into a full answer.