# If start with maximized frame, why do windows open top &bottom, not side by side?

Tags: init-file, window, frames

I have the following in my `.emacs`:

```
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(fullscreen . maximized))
```

And

```
(add-hook 'window-setup-hook
      (lambda ()
        (find-file "FILE.org")
        (shell)))
```

However, these buffers open with one on top, and one on the bottom. As far as I can tell, the `window-setup-hook` is supposed to be run after all frame parameters, so these really should be side by side. If I manually maximize the frame, and then do these two commands in order, it opens them side by side. Any ideas?

EDIT: following Stefan's suggestion, I have submitted a bug report.

Comment: In addition to the variables `split-width-threshold` and `split-height-threshold`, this thread may provide some insight:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/39034/prefer-vertical-splits-over-horizontal-ones  And, here is a link to a detailed answer I wrote up explaining how to display a `shell` buffer in any of four directions (above, below, left, right):  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/28924/2287

Answer (score 1):

Emacs reads the `.emacs` after creating the initial frame, and after that it looks at `default-frame-alist` (and others) to see if it changed and then tries to update the initial frame accordingly.  This update happens fairly late in the startup sequence, so apparently after running `window-setup-hook`.

If you're running Emacs≥27, you can set `default-frame-alist` in your `~/.emacs.d/early-init.el`, so it takes effect even before the initial frame is created, thus completely avoiding these kinds of problems.

Comment: According to the documentation here: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Startup-Summary.html, `window-setup-hook` is supposed to run after setting up the frame parameters (step 27 vs step 26). As far as I can tell, this is why `window-setup-hook` is even a thing.

Comment: @extremeaxe5: Indeed, and the code in `lisp/startup.el` seems to agrees with the doc, so I'm not sure what is the actual origin of the problem.  It probably deserves a bug report.